# htaccess rewrite not redirecting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Would greatly appreciate help on the following.

Am building an app and want to avoid IDOR (insecure direct object reference).

`https://example.com/folder1/index.php?folder2=Xyz&filename=Abc&variable=Pqr`

Using htaccess in "folder1" I want to rewrite the above URL into a clean url ending with folder1 name.

I tried the following and it does not work

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/index-([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)-([a-z]+) https://example.com/folder1/index.php?folder2=$1&filename=$2&variable=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: It will be best if I can get the following: https://example.com/folder1/

Comment: Thanks for helping Anubhava, very curious to get the solution, appreciate if you can suggest a fix!

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. How will `https://example.com/folder1/` map to `https://example.com/folder1/index.php?folder2=Xyz&filename=Abc&variable=Pqr`?

Comment: hmm, can we get the link in the following format https://example.com/folder1/filename/variable. Am just trying to avoid showing the id that will be parsed. Feel free to suggest what best can be done

Comment: For `https://example.com/folder1/index.php?folder2=Xyz&filename=Abc&variable=Pqr` URL you can use: `https://example.com/folder1/Xyz/Abc/Pqr`